# Can I bring xanax (or valium) on a plane?

Tags: air-travel, europe, legal, health, drugs

Is it allowed in Union Europe to bring with you (i.e. in hand luggage) xanax (or valium or any similar anxiety medication)? for personal usage, most likely one box.

Comment: Why would you not?

Comment: Put it an aspirin bottle or something..

Comment: @NeanDerThal So I need to hide that this is xanax? I can't use xanax bottle?

Comment: Checking medicines is a part of the pre-boarding security check, if they allow it I see no reason to prohibit it on planes.

Comment: "Hiding" anything is *probably* a bad idea here.

Comment: @NeanDerThal: That's a truly awful idea, for any number of reasons. **Never** disguise one drug look as another. In particular, never disguise a significant psychoactive drug look like an over-the-counter analgesic.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are two issues that sometimes get confused:

1. **What's allowed on the plane** - This is determined by **security** rules. If a prescription drug is not a liquid that takes you over the liquids limit, then it's allowed. If it takes you over the limit, it's generally still allowed as long as you can prove that it was prescribed to you. Prescription drugs in pill form are not a problem at all.
2. **What's allowed into the country / EU** - This is determined by **customs** rules of each individual country. I don't know the exact EU rules, but I would guess it's similar to US/Canada rules, where less than 1 month supply of a prescription drug is certainly ok, but for some stronger/psychoactive drugs you need to have proof of prescription.

In any case, DO NOT try and hide the fact that it's Xanax by putting it into another bottle, etc. Anything like this will just be a red flag for any official, either security or customs. Prescription drugs should be in original packaging, ideally with your name and prescribing doctor's name / contact info on the packaging.

Comment: I always bring "other evidence" that this was my prescription. My pharmacy sells medication in a bottle in an envelope that is printed with a lot of additional information about me, my doctor, and the drug. It corroborates that this is validly prescribed. I agree - NEVER try to hide a legal prescription drug. Note also that some drugs might be "over the counter" in one country, and "prescription only" in another. If you have an amount that is clearly "for personal use" you are usually OK - but if in doubt, get a note from your doctor.